# Handling multiple image upload with React JS & Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, laravel-5.8

I want to upload multiple images to the database by using axios in reactjs to send the data from client-side to server-side and handle the image upload with laravel in the server-side. My problem is that whenever i try to handle multiple images at the server-side, it doesn't work.

This is my code.

**CLIENT-SIDE (ReactJS)**

CONSTRUCTOR:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: "upload-photo",
            imageArray: [],
            body: '',
            posts: [],
            // image: []
        };
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleBodyChange = this.handleBodyChange.bind(this);
    }
```

HanleFileChange:

```
handleFileChange(e){
        if (e.target.files) {
            const files = Array.from(e.target.files);

            const promises = files.map(file => {
                return (new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    const reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.addEventListener('load', (ev) => {
                        resolve(ev.target.result);
                    });
                    reader.addEventListener('error', reject);
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                }))
            });

            Promise.all(promises).then(images => {
                this.setState({
                    imageArray: images
                })
            }, error => { console.error(error); });
        }
        if (this.props.onChange !== undefined) {
            this.props.onChange(e);
        }
    }
```

HandleSubmitChange:

```
handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // this.postData();
        const formData = new FormData();
        this.state.imageArray.forEach((image_file) => {
             formData.append('file[]', image_file);
        });
        formData.append('body', this.state.body);
        for (let pair of formData.entries()) {
            console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]);
        }
        axios.post('/posts', formData)
            .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                posts: [response.data]
            })
        });
        this.setState({
            body: ''
        });
    }
```

**SERVER-SIDE (LARAVEL)**

```
public function create(Request $request, Post $post) {
        $data = [];
        if ($request->get('file')) {
            foreach ($request->get('file') as $file) {
                $name = time() . '.' . explode('/', explode(':', substr($file, 0, strpos($file, ';')))[1])[1];
                \Image::make($file)->save(public_path('images/') . $name);
                array_push($data, $name);
            }
        }
        $image = json_encode($data);
        // create post
        $createdPost = $request->user()->posts()->create([
            'body' => $request->body,
            'image' => $image
        ]);
        // return the response
        return response()->json($post->with('user')->find($createdPost->id));
    }
```

I expect all uploaded images to be saved to the database. Instead, it throws an error: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`. Therefore, if i remove, the foreach() loop and upload only one image, it saves the image successfully. How can I make use of the loop to save multiple images?

**UPDATE**
This question has been answered in the comments below by @DelenaMalan. I updated the code in this question so that others searching for answers related to this problem can use the code to solve their problem.

Comment: Just a quick guess: `JSON.stringify` the files array before appending it to `formData`

Comment: Try this on the frontend side: `this.state.imageArray.forEach((image_file) => {
        formData.append('file[]', image_file);
    });`

Comment: Thanks @DelenaMalan. That worked like a charm :)

Comment: Good to hear @IsraelObanijesu I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your frontend side you could use `formData.append('file[]', image_file)` to add your image files to the `file` array in the form data, for example:

```
this.state.imageArray.forEach((image_file) => {
    formData.append('file[]', image_file);
});
```